# Jaxb marshalling

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb

Эксперты, подскажите как лучше реализовать маршаллинг. Надо сделать XML файл примерно вида:

```
<teg1>
  <teg2></teg2>
  <teg3></teg3>
  <teg4>
    <teg5></teg5>
  </teg4>
<teg1>
```

Как лучше реализовать, через вложенные классы? или делать отдельные дочерние классы для 1-го тега и 4-го?

Comment: Тут не нужны ни наследники, ни вложенные классы. Если у вас teg* - сложный тип, то надо реализовать это через класс. И в классе для teg1 сделать поля для этих классов и пометить аннотацией

Answer (score 2):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
class Teg1 {
    Teg2 teg2;
    @XmlElement(name = "teg3")
    Tag3 tag3;
    Teg4 teg4;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
class Teg4 {
    Teg5 teg5;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
class Teg2 {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
class Tag3 {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
class Teg5 {
}
```

Comment: Внутри первого класса надо добавить же?@XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "tag2", type=Teg2.class)})
@XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "tag3", type=Teg3.class)})
@XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "tag4", type=Teg4.class)})
И внутри четвёртого аналогично?

Comment: @RusikAltymyshev не обязательно